# Disable Privacy Tools -> Delete My Data

Tags: magento2, configuration

Goal: Remove the "Delete My Data" Button

On a magento 2 store frontend, I'm seeing a button under Privacy tools in the Customer Account that says "Delete My Data". Is this functionality in the vanilla version of Magento 2? If it is standard functionality, I'm looking for the easiest way to remove it. I haven't found a config option yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a OOTB Magento functionality, please check your 3rd party integrations list, maybe there is a configuration which allows you to not show this item.

Comment: Thank you. There are so many packages enabled by default it can be hard to distinguish. Appreciate the feedback

Comment: no problem, but you could just start the 'old school' way - just copy the "Delete My Data" text and search it through the project folder. It should point directly to a file which contains it and you should find the module quite easily.